# Applying constraints to an audio track from getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia, mediastream

Is it possible to apply constraints to a running live audio track?  It doesn't seem to work for me, at least on Chrome v80.

Suppose I have a stream:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    autoGainControl: true
    channelCount: 2
    echoCancellation: true
    noiseSuppression: true
  },
  video: false
});
```

Now, later on I want to change some of those parameters:

```
for (const track of stream.getAudioTracks()) {
  track.applyConstraints({
    autoGainControl: false,
    echoCancellation: false,
    noiseSuppression: false
  });
}
```

This has no effect.  If I call `track.getConstraints()`, I see my new constraints but audibly they have no effect until I reload the page and apply them from the beginning.  Additionally, when I call `track.getSettings()`, I see that my new constraints *haven't* been applied.

I have also tried calling `track.enabled = false` before applying the constraints, with `track.enabled = true` afterwards, with no luck.

Any advice on how to get this to work without making a fresh call to `getUserMedia()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SO user [jib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918910/jib), which works on Firefox and adapter.js projects wrote a [blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/fiddle-of-the-week-audio-constraints/) in 2017 about this exact feature.

Here is how they did apply the constraints to the track:

```
async function apply(c) {
  await track.applyConstraints(Object.assign(track.getSettings(), c));
  update();
}
```

`c` is an object with the particular constraints to add.

They do it this way because all the properties that are omitted when passing the 
[MediaTrackConstraints](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/fiddle-of-the-week-audio-constraints/) dictionary will get reset to their defaults when [applied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints).

Now, your solution should have worked too for the properties you did set.

---

So using this fiddle I did try the few UAs I have on my macOS machine:

#### Chrome

As you reported, **settings are not applied.**

Here is [the issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796964) tracking the upcoming implementation.

From this issue's comments you can also find a workaround which implies requesting a new MediaStream from the same `deviceId` as the one you got, and applying the desired constraints.

[Here is a fork of jib's fiddle with such a workaround.](https://jsfiddle.net/rfqx1o24/) Note that the `deviceId` is gotten from `track.getSettings()`

```
async function apply(c) {
  track.stop(); // required
  const new_constraints = Object.assign(track.getSettings(), c, );
  const new_stream = await gUM({ audio: new_constraints });

  updateSpectrum( audio.srcObject = new_stream );
  track = new_stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
  update();
}
```

#### Firefox

**Works seamlessly.**

#### Safari

**Badly crashes.** On my machine, running the original fiddle, with only the tweak of the spectrum will completely crash the gUM of the whole browser. 
 - The current stream is stopped
 - Any attempt to get a new stream fails - until reboot of the whole app.

The forked fiddle we made for Chrome at least doesn't crash, but it doesn't seem to produce any audible change either...

Comment: Thanks as always @Kaiido.  You always seem to be able to find the Chrome bugs for all the new stuff I keep trying to use.  :-)